# Bifrost JS Listener

Tags: bifrost

I just saw that there is a new release of bifrost. Without checking deep into the code I want to ask two questions here first of which I think more people are interested in the answers:

So my questions:

Each session creates a listener. Within bifrost a stellar keypair is created and a ETH/BTC public key is given. Lets assume we refresh the browser, we will get new keypairs and public addresses.
If we move the JS implementation to a node server, we keep the listener until a transaction is completed. But we still have the problem that if the node crashes, we cannot recreate the listener (listen to the same ETH/BTC address as before the crash).

1) Can we do this in any way? I haven't found a way yet.

2) Is there a possibility to not create stellar keypairs on every transaction but to provide a fixed keypair while setting up the listener? That could be optional (if param not set create new keypair, else take param keypair)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to connecting to the stream of previously created address you can do this, but you would either need to change JS-SDK code or write your own client code. All you need to do is to start streaming:

```
${bifrostURL}/events?stream=${address}
```

endpoint where `${address}` is Bitcoin or Ethereum address given you by the Bifrost server.

> Is there a possibility to not create stellar keypairs on every transaction but to provide a fixed keypair while setting up the listener? That could be optional (if param not set create new keypair, else take param keypair)

Currently you can do this by updating Bifrost JS SDK code.